# Get sum of values in one sheet and paste the value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro for the following criteria.

1) Cell value has to be updated in WorkSheet 1. This value has to be pulled from WorkSheet 2 which contains multiple rows of data.

2) To pull the value, first, filter has to be set in Column 'B' of Worksheet 2 to select only where values 'Test' exist. After this, filter has to be set in Column 'D' to select only where values 'Variance' exist. Once that filter is set, I need the sum of values in column 'E'.

3) That sum of values needs to be updated in cell I5 of Worksheet 1?

Can someone please help me with this code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this without using VBA. You just need to change it to fit your needs.

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C4;A1:A4;"Test";B1:B4;"Variance")
```